# FOSUserBundle override action of a controller

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to override the editAction in ProfileController.php but it's doesn't work. I can override template and form with success but not the actions of controllers.

#### app/config.yml

```
# FOS UserBundle Configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Intranet\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: intranet_user_registration
    profile:
        form:
            type: intranet_user_profile
```

#### old src/Intranet/UserBundle/Controller/ProfileController.php

```
<?php

namespace Intranet\UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ProfileController as BaseController;

class ProfileController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * Edit the user
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request)
    {
        var_dump($request) die(); // just for the test
    }
}
```

#### new src/Intranet/UserBundle/Controller/ProfileController.php

```
<?php

namespace Intranet\UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ProfileController as BaseController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

class ProfileController extends BaseController
{
    public function editAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }

        /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_INITIALIZE, $event);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->container->get('fos_user.profile.form.factory');

        $form = $formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
            $form->bind($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
                $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');

                $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
                $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_SUCCESS, $event);

                $userManager->updateUser($user);

                if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                    $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_profile_show');
                    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
                }

                $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

                return $response;
            }
        }

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse(
            'FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit.html.'.$this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine'),
            array('form' => $form->createView())
        );
    }
}
```

#### src/Intranet/UserBundle/IntranetUserBundle.php

```
<?php

namespace Intranet\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class IntranetUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

No error message, SF2 ignore my override :/

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: Ok clear:cache solved the problem now I copy/paste the code of editAction (I edited my post)
And I've this error : **This user does not have access to this section**

Comment: Check the access_control section of your security.yml file.

Comment: Guys **YOU NEED TO CLEAR THE CACHE IN ORDER TO OVERRIDE A CONTROLLER**!!!! I spent some time with this arrghh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found, the controller need the same use of his parent

#### Last version of ProfileController :

```
namespace Intranet\UserBundle\Controller;

    /* ALL USE IS REQUIRED !!!! */
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ProfileController as BaseController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

class ProfileController extends BaseController
{
    public function editAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }

        /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_INITIALIZE, $event);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->container->get('fos_user.profile.form.factory');

        $form = $formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
            $form->bind($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
                $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');

                $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
                $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_SUCCESS, $event);

                $userManager->updateUser($user);

                if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                    $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_profile_show');
                    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
                }

                $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

                return $response;
            }
        }

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse(
            'FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit.html.'.$this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine'),
            array('form' => $form->createView())
        );
    }
}
```