# How to override ProfileController in FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I need to override FOSUserBundle's `ProfileController` to add some features.

How can I override the controller?

Comment: the answer is in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094367/fosuserbundle-override-action-of-a-controller

Comment: see this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094367/fosuserbundle-override-action-of-a-controller

Answer (score 1):

Just extend the bundle itself:

```
class MyBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

And then create a controller with the same name. Of course this only works when you use the Symfony2 specific terminology: `MyBundle:Controller:myAction`.

Comment: i do it and i override formregistration and i make a controllerprofile but when i make echo for test but no result

Comment: i override the profile controller when i add :$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();                                     $notif = $em1->getRepository('PublishDemandsBundle:Notification')->findBy(array('seen' => false, 'typeevent' => demande));                    the error is:Call to undefined method Register\UserBundle\Controller\ProfileController::getDoctrine()

Comment: The issue producing `Call to undefined method ... getDoctrine()` has been resolved in this **[question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22841440/1832745)**.