# Symfony2 - Call to undefined method getDoctrine() when overriding FOSUserBundle's ProfileController

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

When I override FOSUserBundle's `ProfileController` and add these lines:

```
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $resultat = $em->getRepository('PublishDemandsBundle:Demands')->findAll();
```

I get the following error:

> Call to undefined method
>   Register\UserBundle\Controller\ProfileController::getDoctrine() in
>   ProfileController.php.

Comment: How does your ProfileController look like? Looks like you did not extend the default controller class.

Comment: FOSUserBundle's ProfileController extends [`ContainerAware`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/ProfileController.php#L29) instead of [`Controller`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php). Therefore you need to: either use `$this->container->get('doctrine')` or add the  [`getDoctrine()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L218) to the overriden ProfileController yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Adding this alias-method to the controller fixed the issue:

```
public function getDoctrine()
{
    return $this->container->get('doctrine');
}
```